# How to create a list of words as long as the word is not a word within a list of tuples

Tags: python

I have some words:

```
wordlist = ['change', 'my', 'diaper', 'please']
```

I also have a list of tuples that I need to check against:

```
mylist = [('verb', 'change'), ('prep', 'my')]
```

What I want to do is create a list out of all the words that are not in the list of tuples.

So the result of this example would be `['diaper', 'please']`

What I tried seems to create duplicates:

```
[word for tuple in mylist for word in wordlist if word not in tuple]
```

How do I generate a list of the words not in the tuple-list, and do it as efficiently as possible?

No use of sets.

Edit: chose answer based on following restriction of `set`

Comment: have you tried iterating through the list checking each word in list against each word in tuple?

Comment: I have tried. But what's throwing me off there is that I need to access each tuple individually to make use of the `in` operator. Thus the nested loops, the errors, and something tells me its not very efficient. @Stanley

Comment: youre right! but searching in general isn't very memory and/or effiency friendly

Comment: You could probably change On^2 to Onlogn if you use a binary search. You'd need to presort the list of words you were searching on up front.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is a oneliner using list comprehension

```
[word for word in wordlist if word not in [ w[1] for w in mylist ]]
```

The inner list, `[ w[1] for w in mylist ]` extracts the second element from the tuple list.

The outer list, `[word for word in wordlist if word not in innerlist]` extracts the words filtering out the ones in the just extracted list.

P.S. I assumed you wanted to filter only the second element of the tuple list.

Answer (score 2):

Make a `set` of known words from your tuples list:

```
myList = [('verb', 'change'), ('prep', 'my')]
known_words = set(tup[1] for tup in myList)
```

then use it as you did before:

```
wordlist = ['change', 'my', 'diaper', 'please']
out = [word  for word in wordlist if word not in known_words]

print(out)
# ['diaper', 'please']
```

Checking if an item exists in a set is O(1), while checking in a list or tuple is O(length of the list), so it is really worth using sets in such cases.

Also, if you don't care about the order of the words and want to remove duplicates, you could do:

```
unique_new_words = set(wordlist) - known_words
print(unique_new_words)
# {'diaper', 'please'}
```

Comment: ha! you beat my to the last step! i'll leave it out of my answer then. +1

Answer (score 1):

this is a version where i flatten (using [`itertools.chain`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/itertools.html?highlight=chain#itertools.chain)) your tuples into a [`set`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html?highlight=set#set) and compare against that set (using a `set` will speed up the lookup for the `in` operator):

```
from itertools import chain

wordlist = ['change', 'my', 'diaper', 'please']
mylist = [('verb', 'change'), ('prep', 'my')]
veto = set(chain(*mylist))   # {'prep', 'change', 'verb', 'my'}

print([word for word in wordlist if word not in veto])
# ['diaper', 'please']
```

Answer (score 1):

I have made a an assumption, that tuple[1] would have only one element, if not that would need a small change.

```
[word for word in wordlist if word not in [tuple[1] for tuple in mylist]]
```